# Classpath issue: Scala WAR webapp (jetty) fails to load on Windows but run flawlessly on Linux

Tags: scala

On Windows 8.1 every time I start jetty (9.12) with

java -jar start.jar

It is able to find and deploy my WAR, but then shows an error message:

```
>     15:14:17.754 [main] ERROR n.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider - Failed to Boot! Your application may not run properly
>     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Seq
>             at net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats$.<init>(Formats.scala:175)
> ~[lift-json-2.0.jar:2.0]
>             at net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats$.<clinit>(Formats.scala)
> ~[lift-json-2.0.jar:2.0]
>             at blah.rest.RestAPI$.<init>(RestAPI.scala:16)
> ~[classes/:na]
>             at blah.rest.RestAPI$.<clinit>(RestAPI.scala)
> ~[classes/:na]
>             at bootstrap.liftweb.Boot.boot(Boot.scala:28) ~[classes/:na]
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
>             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
>     
>     ....
```

And

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Seq
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_03]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:436) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:389) ~[na:na]
        ... 65 common frames omitted
```

On the other hand, when I deploy the same war in my Ubuntu 13.10 environment, it runs without complaining anything.

I have set my CLASSPATH variable to include scala (something like .;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\lib;C:\scala\lib;C:\scala\lib\scala-library.jar), and SCALA_HOME appropriately.

I also tried

java -jar start.jar -lib=blah....

Is there anything I haven't done right / anything extra I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by changing dependency libraries compiled against a single corresponding Scala version.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a classpath problem. Somehow it's not able to find Scala libraries.

I would suggest to run `jconsole` - it comes together with standard JDK package. Select the java process in it on Windows and Linux and compare classpaths. For example I get this on my machine in `jconsole`:

```
VM arguments: 

Class path: 
/somepath/myapp.jar

Library path: 
/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib

Boot class path: 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/netx.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rhino.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/classes
```

Note that my app is packaged as a single jar and this jar itself is on the classpath. It contains `scala-library-2.10.3.jar` and `scala-reflect-2.10.3.jar` packaged within. Perhaps in your case the jar does not have Scala libraries and they are not on the classpath either.

Comment: I checked on both Tomcat and Jetty. They are there. One really weird thing is the WAR apparently contains scala-library.jar etc. already, under WEB-INF\lib